# I need to speed up this summation

Tags: performance-tuning, summation

I tried solving this problem on my own but I cant find a proper solution.

I need to evaluate the following equation: $\sum\limits_{m=1\\m\neq i}^n{\left(\dfrac{v_m~(\lambda_i\cdot B-A)~u_i}{(\lambda_m-\lambda_i)\cdot x_m}\right)\cdot u_m-\left(\dfrac{v_i~B~u_i}{2\cdot x_i}\right)\cdot u_i~,~i=1,...,n}$

$A$ and $B$: real non-symmetric matricies

$v_i$: $i$th left-Eigenvector

$u_i$: $i$th right-Eigenvector

$\lambda_i$: $i$th Eigenvalue

The computation time is kinda fast for $n\leq250$ and it gets significantly slower for greater $n$. I need to evaluate this equation for at least $n=500$ and this takes forever. I posted my current "solution" below and would like to ask if there is a chance to speed up this computation.

```
n = 250;
A = RandomReal[{1*10^-7, 1*10^-6}, {n, n}];
B = RandomReal[{1*10^-12, 1*10^-11}, {n, n}];
X = RandomReal[{1*10^-12, 1*10^-11}, {n}];

{EW, EVR} = Eigensystem[{A, B}];
{EW, EVL} = Eigensystem[{Transpose[A], Transpose[B]}];

ParallelTable[
  Sum[If[m == i, 0, 
    (EVL[[m]].(EW[[i]]*B - A).EVR[[i]])/((EW[[m]] - EW[[i]])*X[[m]])*EVR[[m]]], {m, 1, n}]  
    - EVR[[i]]*(EVL[[i]].B.EVR[[i]])/(2*X[[i]]), {i, 1, n}];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No MMA on this machine to check, but from eyeballing your code the first thing I'd test is not checking `If[m == I` at every iteration; just iterate over the indices where `m != i`.  Generic lesson - don't bury `if` statements at the bottom of deep loop nests if they can be lifted out,

Comment: If $u_i$ is a right eigenvector to the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$, i.e., $(\lambda_i \, B - A) \, u_i = 0$, shouldn't the sum simply vanish? Only the summand for $m = i$ should remain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that

$$ A \, u_i = \lambda_i \, B \, u_i$$

and

$$ v_m^T \, A = \lambda_m \, v_m^T \, B. $$

Then
$$
    v_m^T( \lambda_i \,B - A) \, u_i
    =
    (\lambda_i \, v_m^T \, B - \lambda_m \, v_m^T \, B) \, u_i
    =
    (\lambda_i - \lambda_m) \, v_m^T \, B \, u_i,
$$
hence
$$
    \frac{v_m^T( \lambda_i \,B - A) \, u_i}{(\lambda_m-\lambda_i) \, x_m} \, u_m
    =
    - u_m \frac{v_m^T \, B \, u_i }{x_m}.
$$

Also notice that if $\lambda_i \neq 0$ and $\lambda_j \neq 0$, then
$$
    \lambda_m \, v_m^T \, B \, u_i 
    =
    v_m^T \, A \, u_i 
    = 
    \lambda_i \, v_m^T \, B \, u_i,
$$
hence
$$
    v_m^T \, A \, u_i = v_m^T \, B \, u_i = 0 \quad \text{for $i \neq m$}.
$$
This leads us to
$$
    \frac{v_m^T( \lambda_i \,B - A) \, u_i}{(\lambda_m-\lambda_i) \, x_m} \, u_m
    =
    - u_m \frac{v_m^T \, B \, u_i }{x_m}
    =
    - \delta_{mi} \frac{v_m^T \, B \, u_m }{x_m} \, u_m
$$

**Btw.** Be careful with the ordering of the eigenvalues:

```
RandomSeed[123];
n = 250;
A = RandomReal[{1*10^-7, 1*10^-6}, {n, n}];
B = RandomReal[{1*10^-12, 1*10^-11}, {n, n}];
X = RandomReal[{1*10^-12, 1*10^-11}, {n}];
{EWR, EVR} = Eigensystem[{A, B}];
{EWL, EVL} = Eigensystem[{Transpose[A], Transpose[B]}];

Max[Abs[EWR - EWL]]
perm = Flatten[Nearest[EWL -> "Index", EWR]];
EWR = EWR[[perm]];
EVR = EVR[[perm]];
```

> 1.99437

As you can see, due to small numerical errors, the orderings of left and right eigensystems do not coincide. This is easy to repair:

```
perm = Flatten[Nearest[EWL -> "Index", EWR]];
EWR = EWR[[perm]];
EVR = EVR[[perm]];
Max[Abs[EWR - EWL]/Abs[EWL]]
```

> 1.42593*10^-13

Comment: Thank you so much. I completely missed that. This helps alot.

Comment: Great! You're welcome!